# adal policy identifier in adal4j

Tags: adal, adal4j

I try to push some data to a cloud using a adal4j token but I didn't get acces because of the policy identifier.

An existing app uses the adal library and uses a policy identifier String using the adal

```
AutenticationContext.acquireToken()
```

This method isn't supported with the same params in adal4j. So how can I set a policy to the token acquisition with the adal4j library?

I hope someone can help me.

Best Regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Were you developing an app integrate with Azure AD B2C tenant? 
As far as I know, the adal4j library doesn't support to integrate with Azure AD B2C at present. You may consider to initiate the request from scratch based on the OAuth 2.0 code grant flow for the Azure Active Directory [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code).

And if you want the adal4j to support it, you can also to submit the new issue from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/issues).